# Power Automate and PowerApps connection to upload files and save it in SharePoint

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am developing an app where users can upload files (all types) to the SharePoint document library.
I get following error in PowerApps:

> Runtime error: the server didn't receive a response from an upstream server

and following error in Power Automate:

> Unable to process template language expressions in action
> 'Create_file' inputs at line '1' and column '7802':
> 'The template language function 'base64ToBinary'
> was invoked with a parameter that is not valid.
> The value cannot be decoded from base64 representation.'.

please how to solve this error

Comment: It would be beneficial to see the steps you have in your Flow.